# trying to set up "wrong key pressed" error within while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I'm learning Python with 'Learn Python The Hard Way',
I am currently writing a simple text adventure.

my problem is in the 'combat' part of the code (provided below). only the numbers 1 and 2 are meant to be pressed by the user. if a different int is pressed, it correctly throws up 'sorry don't understand', but if a letter is pressed, it freaks out and exits saying, (quite rightly) that it was expecting an int. obviously my question is, how do I set it to expect both, and throw up the error when a letter is pressed?

Thanks in advance :)

```
        while True:
            player_dmg = randint(1, 10)
            enemy_dmg = randint(1, 10)

            if enemy_hp < 0:
                os.system('clear')
                print "[ENEMY NUTRALISED]"
                print
                print hit_e
                raw_input()
                return 'forth_area'
            elif player_hp < 0:
                return 'death'

            else:
                print "[COMBAT OPTIONS]"
                print "1. Attack"
                print "2. Defend"
                print
                choice = raw_input("*>>*")
                choice = int(choice)
                print
            if choice == 1:
                enemy_hp = enemy_hp - player_dmg
                print "[ENEMY STATUS: %d]" % enemy_hp
                print "[DAMAGE DONE: %d]" % player_dmg
                print
                player_hp = player_hp - enemy_dmg
                print "[DAMAGE RECIVED: %d]" % enemy_dmg
                print "[CURRENT STATUS: %d]" % player_hp
            elif choice  == 2:
                enemy_hp = enemy_hp - player_dmg / 2
                print "[ENEMY STATUS %d]" % enemy_hp
                print "[DAMAGE DONE %d]" % player_dmg
                print
                player_hp = player_hp - enemy_dmg
                player_hp = player_hp + 3
                print "[DAMAGE RECIVED: %d]" % enemy_dmg
                print "[CURRENT STATUS: %d]" % player_hp
                print
            else:
                print no_understand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
choice = raw_input("*>>*")
choice = int(choice)
# . . .
if choice == 1:
# . . .
elif choice == 2:
```

The simplest fix is to use:

```
choice = raw_input("*>>*")
# . . .
if choice == '1':
# . . .
elif choice == '2':
```

`raw_input` returns a string. Why convert it to a number? Just test for text `'1'` and `'2'`, etc. It also makes it easier to add character commands (like `'q'` for quit).

Comment: wow, pretty simple! for some reason i thought it had to be set as an int for the random number stuff to work properly. Thanks very much for the quick responses guys!

Comment: hmmm..ive just tried this way and now the error message comes up no matter what i push (1 or 2 no longer work)

Comment: This is working on my machine. Here are some things to try. Did you remember to remove the line: `choice = int(choice)`? Are you sure you have quotes around '1', '2', etc., ex. `if choice == '1':`? I notice raw_input is returning Unicode so you could try: `if choice == u'1':`. If this still isn't working, after `raw_input` add a line `print 'CHOICE', type(choice), choice` so you can see exactly what you have to match.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this.

I think a simple solution would be with an exception.

```
try:
    choice = int(choice)
except:
    choice = None
```

It just tries to cast the `choice` into an int type.  If it fails, the except block is run, and sets choice to None, so the if/elif blocks will not run.

OK, not the simplest, @jimhark has a simpler approach.

It seems in this case, there is little value in converting the input to an integer.

Comment: My approach is nice for when you want to force the user to enter  integers (e.g. how many gold coins do you want give me?), but it seems like @jimhark has a more general solution, as you may want to accept alphabet characters at some point.

Comment: @jgritty. Thanks. You're answer is good too, honestly it better matches what was actually asked. You make a good point in that depending on context, your approach may be better. (Though I'd recommend catching the specific exception, i.e. `except ValueError as e:`.)

Comment: for this bit (the combat) your method works fine. however i see the advantage of using Jims, and will do so for other parts of the project. thanks again, this is my first time posting a question and didn't expect such quick responses! im sure you will hear from me again soon :)

Comment: Usually I can't type fast enough to answer the easy python questions.  And definitely, `except ValueError as e:` is more correct, but I was trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644220/1481060 and suggested using the standard module `cmd` that handles these sorts of command-loops.

It should give you the ability to add verbs like **kill**, **look** etc...to your game.

--

You may also want to model your Game as Objects so that you don't keep too many variables around as I can imagine that when something gets `hit` the health goes down as does the damage and stamina etc etc.

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TKcVg7OXVg which  should add to the experience.

Comment: great, thanks again, just watched the first one and learned loads! will watch the rest soon :)